# C linked list printing extra 0 at the beginning

Tags: c, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list, function-definition

this program is not completely ready yet, so not all funcionalities are coded.

However, I am facing a problem when it comes to the very basic functionality: adding the node in
the end of the linked list.

I am somehow getting a mysterious number "0" in the beginning of the linked list and I don't see
where it's coming from

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct USER{
    int number;
    struct USER *next;
}USER;

USER* allocMem(USER* newUser){
    if ((newUser = (USER*)malloc(sizeof(USER))) == NULL ){
        perror("Memory allocation failed.");
        exit(1);
    }
    newUser->number;
    printf("A list has been created.\n");
    return newUser;
}

int newNode(USER* start){
    int num;
    USER *newUser = NULL; 
    USER *value = NULL;
    if ((newUser = (USER*)malloc(sizeof(USER))) == NULL ){
        perror("Memory allocation failed.");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nGive a new number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    newUser->number = num;
    newUser->next = NULL;
    if (start == NULL){
        start = newUser;
    }else{
        value = start;
        while(value->next != NULL){
            value = value->next;
        }
        value->next = newUser;
    }
    return 0;
}

int newNode_position(USER* start){
    USER *newUser = NULL;
    USER *value = NULL;
    int num;
    int position;
    if ((newUser = (USER*)malloc(sizeof(USER))) == NULL ){
        perror("Memory allocation failed.");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nGive a new number: ");

    scanf("%d", &newUser->number);

    printf("Into which node do you want to place the number: ");
    scanf("%d", &position);
    value = start;
    for(int i = 1; i < position; i++){  
        value = value->next;
        
    }
    newUser->next = value->next; 
    value->next = newUser;

    value = NULL;
    value = start;
    printf("The following numbers are in the list: \n");
    while(value->next != NULL){
        printf("%d ", value->number);
        value = value->next;
    }

    return 0;
}


void print(USER *start){
    USER *value = NULL;
    value = start;
    printf("Following numbers are now in the list: \n");
    while(value->next != NULL){
        printf("%d ", value->number);
        value = value->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}


void freeMem(USER* start){ 
    USER *value = NULL;
    while (start != NULL){
        value = start;   
        start = value->next;
        free(value); 
    }
}



int main(void){
    int choice;
    USER *start = NULL;
    printf("This program let's you create a linked list and manage it.\n");
    do {
        printf("\n1) Create a list\n");
        printf("2) Insert a new node in the end\n");
        printf("3) Insert a new node in the middle, to a specified position\n");
        printf("4) Clear the list\n");
        printf("5) Delete certain node from the list\n");
        printf("6) Print the list\n");
        printf("0) Quit\n");
        printf("Your choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch(choice){
            case 1:
            start = allocMem(start);  
            break;
            case 2:
            newNode(start);
            break;
            case 3:
            newNode_position(start);
            case 4:
            freeMem(start);
            break;
            case 6:
            print(start);
            break;
            case 0:
            printf("\nThank you for using the program.");
            break;
            default:
            printf("Unknown choice.");
            break;
        }
    } while(choice != 0);
    
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

**As I create the list and add number: "2" three times in the end of the list, the output is:**

0, 2, 2

**When it should be**

2, 2, 2

I can't find why it's printing the mysterious 0 at the beginning.

Comment: in function `allocMem`, the `newUser->number` element is not initialized and has zero by default. That's where your zero is coming from.

Comment: `allocMem()` creates a list with one user in it. That's the first one that `print()` shows.

Comment: You're also not initializing the `next` pointer of the first user.

Comment: Moreover, when you're printing the values, you stop at the node which has `next==NULL`, which is the last node, so the last node's value doesn't get printed.

Comment: Debugger........

Answer (score 3):

The function `allocMem` creates a node with uninitialized data members `number` and `next`.

```
USER* allocMem(USER* newUser){
    if ((newUser = (USER*)malloc(sizeof(USER))) == NULL ){
        perror("Memory allocation failed.");
        exit(1);
    }
    newUser->number;
    printf("A list has been created.\n");
    return newUser;
}
```

that results in undefined behavior of the program.

The function print that is incorrect

```
void print(USER *start){
    USER *value = NULL;
    value = start;
    printf("Following numbers are now in the list: \n");
    while(value->next != NULL){
        printf("%d ", value->number);
        value = value->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

outputs this indeterminate value stored in the data member `number` of the first node and moreover it does not output the value in the last node due to the condition of the while statement

```
    while(value->next != NULL){
```

Actually the function `allocMem` is redundant and should be removed. This declaration

```
USER *start = NULL;
```

already creates an empty list.

There are other drawbacks in the code. For example the function `freeMem` actually does not clear the list because the pointer `start` declared in main will be unchanged after calling the function and as a result will be invalid.

Either you should declare the function liek

```
USER * freeMem(USER* start){ 
    USER *value = NULL;
    while (start != NULL){
        value = start;   
        start = value->next;
        free(value); 
    }

    return start;
}
```

and call it like

```
case 4:
start = freeMem(start);
break;
```

Or you can declare it like

```
void freeMem( USER **start){ 
    while ( *start != NULL ){
        USER *value = *start;   
        start = &( *start )->next;
        free(value); 
    }
}
```

and call it like

```
case 4:
freeMem( &start);
break;
```

Or for example the function `newNode_position` again can invoke undefined behavior at least because in this for loop

```
value = start;
for(int i = 1; i < position; i++){  
    value = value->next;
    
}
```

there is no check whether the pointer `value` is equal to `NULL`.

And moreover the function does not change the pointer `start` declared in main.